# How To Detect When Other Code Setting e.Handled = true?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, telerik

Using C#, .NET 4, WPF.

I have a Telerik rich text control that is losing certain key events (tab, backspace, delete, and the arrow keys are specifics).

For debugging purposes I have added handlers for PreviewKeyDown, KeyDown, CommandExecuting, and DocumentContentChanged. The behavior presents both with and without the handlers present, in both DEBUG and RELEASE mode.

If I press a key other than those listed above I get the events in the order listed above. As an example, if I press the 'a' key I get PreviewKeyDown, KeyDown, CommandExecuting, and DocumentContentChanged.

If I press the right arrow key I get PreviewKeyDown and no other of the events fire.

My suspicion is that there is *something* trapping the KeyDown event at some point in the message chain before it gets to me and setting e.Handled = true.

Is there any tool available that would allow me to detect the KeyDown event and see in what code it's e.Handled is modified? I know I'm stretching here...

Thanks!

rjsjr

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). It can tell you, which Element set handled = true. 
If you need to process these events, you can use [EventManager.RegisterClassHandler()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597874%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).